# How to a handle a large number of axis labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, axis-labels, xticks

As a beginner this is my first time using larger datasets for clustering. Can someone please help me with this problem.
Here is my code:

```
df1=BAR[['symbol','average_price']]  
plt.figure(figsize=(40,30))  
plt.scatter(df1['symbol'],df1['average_price']) 
plt.xlabel('SYMBOL',fontsize=15) 
plt.ylabel('AVERAGE_PRICE',fontsize=15)  
plt.xticks(rotation=90,fontsize=12)    
plt.show()
```

Here is my scatterplot:

[image]

Comment: how many unique symbols do you have?

Comment: It's 505 unique symbols

Comment: Do you want them all displayed on the figure?

Comment: No, it's not must! But, I am just curious to know how to handle these kind of plots in future. Is there any methods or ways by which we could handle these types of plots with larger unique xticks symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy option is to change the figure size and make it really big (as you did). Or you could also change the ratio and make the figure only really broad.
But for me I only see the effect if I do not use an interactive backend but for example use `Agg`. If you than save the figure and look at the `png` file you can see the extra space.
Another thing I tend to do is to arrange the labels in a smarter way to use the space a little better.

For example you could move every second label down and draw a longer tick, in my opinion this looks less cramped.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def change_tick_length(ax, i, size):
    h = ax.xaxis.get_majorticklines()
    i = np.ravel_multi_index((i, 0), (len(h)//2, 2))
    h[i].set_markersize(size)


n = 200
new_tick_length = 70
n_whitespace = int(new_tick_length / 3.3)  # found this ratio works for me

labels = [f"Dummy{i}" for i in range(n)]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40, 15))
ax = fig.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
ax.plot(range(n))
ax.set_xticks(range(n))

for i, l in enumerate(labels):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        labels[i] = f"{l}{' ' * n_whitespace}"
        change_tick_length(ax=ax, i=i, size=new_tick_length)

ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
plt.savefig('dummy')
```

[image: a lot of ticks]

Comment: It's really a good idea!! Thank you mate for your help. Its really helpful.